# Can udev monitor network storage mounting & unmounting?

Tags: mount, udev, nas

I want to setup notification whenever any network drive is mounted or unmounted. (Basically I want to run a custom script, whenever any network storage is mounted or unmounted). I think udev can do this, but I don't know how to write udev rule for such a task.

When I mount a network share using the following command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=user,password=pwd //ipaddr/sharename mountpoint
```

the filesystem is successfully mounted I can see the following `sysfs` entries were created:

```
/sys/class/bdi/cifs-<num>/ & /sys/devices/virtual/bdi/cifs-<num>
```

Can `udev` monitor such a change? If yes, how does the rule look like?
Or is there some other method to do this?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got it working, but there is one problem:

Rule file (`/etc/udev/rules/99-nas.rule`) looks like this:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="bdi", ACTION=="add"   RUN+="/home/user/myscript.sh"
SUBSYSTEM=="bdi", ACTION=="remove"   RUN+="/home/user/myscript.sh"
```

(`myscript.sh` uses: `mount -t cifs` to list all mounted CIFS devices)

The problem is: when the first remote storage is mounted, then output of `mount -t cifs` is null. From second mount or unmount everything is normal.
I don't know how to solve this problem.